# Keycloak token exchange fails with "invalid_token" error

Tags: oauth, keycloak, openid-connect, openid

I have two Keycloak instances running locally. They are connected via OIDC. Everything works so far - I can login via any of Keycloak instances.

Now I am trying to setup [token exchage](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_token-exchange) and it fails with "invalid_token" error. I want to do "external to internal" token exchange. There are following Keycloak logs showing that Keycloak sending HTTP GET request with the token I provided to another Keycloak instance to get user info:

```
08:14:36,523 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 >> "GET /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
08:14:36,523 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 >> "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSU...[\r][\n]"
```

and the response is 401:

```
08:14:36,530 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
08:14:36,530 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
08:14:36,530 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 << "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
08:14:36,530 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 << "Referrer-Policy: no-referrer[\r][\n]"
08:14:36,530 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 << "Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 08:14:36 GMT[\r][\n]"
08:14:36,530 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
08:14:36,530 DEBUG http-outgoing-19 << "WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="master", error="invalid_token", error_description="Token verification failed"[\r][\n]"
```

The weird part is this: when I am sending the same response with `curl` using the same token that does not work in Keycloak - it works:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:8050/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo' \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N...'

{"name":"r o","sub":"fff41a6f-6910-4419-8d46-7630b57ed420","email_verified":true,"preferred_username":"ttt","given_name":"r","family_name":"o"}
```

All permissions for token exchange set up (otherwise it does not send the request at all and it fails with another error).

What am I missing here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. It worked using curl, because I was using `localhost`, and it did not work in Keycloak, because `Keycloak` used local IP address (`192.168.X.X`). The core reason is in the token that has to be exchanged. Field `iss` must match the IP/Host that is sending the request. In other words, in the token that I used to test token exchange, `iss` was equal `http://localhost...`, and I also used `localhost` in curl request. After using token that's been issued from `192.168.XX`, token exchange started to work.

Actually, from a security perspective it totally makes sense. Only issuer of the token should be able to use it to get user info.